# how to execute flutter app in Chromium browser on linux?

Tags: linux, flutter, chromium, flatpak

how to execute flutter app in Chromium in Flat-pack Linux? i tried `#CHROME_EXECUTABLE=/snap/bin/chromium; export CHROME_EXECUTABLE` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are using snaps now , to use Flat-pack Chromium edit the `.bashrc` file by adding :

```
CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.chromium.Chromium/current/active/export/bin/org.chromium.Chromium"; export CHROME_EXECUTABLE
```

Comment: thanks it worked, you need just to restart your terminal or vscode

Comment: The path was `~/.local/share/flatpak/app/org.chromium.Chromium/current/active/export/bin/org.chromium.Chromium` for me.

Answer (score 1):

CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/usr/bin/chromium-browser"; export CHROME_EXECUTABLE

Answer (score 0):

edit file ~/.bashrc

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

at the end add this line at the end

```
CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/bin/chromium-browser"; export CHROME_EXECUTABLE
```

restart vscode and you are ready